# Parsing XML with Python Returning "Nonetype Object Not Callable" TypeError after it was working just fine

Tags: python-3.x, xml, nonetype

I'm trying to create a command line tool to parse xml files for attributes input by the user. I'm nowhere near the point that that really matters but: As I started working through the documentation for BeautifulSoup and lxml and adapting it to the file I'm testing against, at first my print statements were working just fine and returning the data as expected, but now suddenly it is giving me "Nonetype object is not callable" error. I even had it working with using input() as a parameter for the findTag1 variable. And then as stated it just suddenly stopped accepting any of the attributes I typed into both input() when i had it written in, and just like pictured below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import argparse


with open('Sample1.xml.xml', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

Bs_data = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")

findTag1 = Bs_data.findaAll('CATALOG')
findTag1Child = Bs_data.find({'COMMON': ''})
findTag1Child2 = Bs_data.find({'BOTANICAL'})




# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(findTag1Child)
    print(findTag1)
    print(findTag1Child2)
```

And the xml file being used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl'?>
<CATALOG>
    <PLANT>
    <COMMON>rose</COMMON>
    <BOTANICAL>canadensis</BOTANICAL>
    <ZONE>4</ZONE>
    <LIGHT>Shady</LIGHT>
    <PRICE>202</PRICE>
    <AVAILABILITY>446</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
    <PLANT>
    <COMMON>mango</COMMON>
    <BOTANICAL>sunny</BOTANICAL>
    <ZONE>3</ZONE>
    <LIGHT>shady</LIGHT>
    <PRICE>301</PRICE>
    <AVAILABILITY>569</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
    <PLANT>
    <COMMON>Marigold</COMMON>
    <BOTANICAL>palustris</BOTANICAL>
    <ZONE>4</ZONE>
    <LIGHT>Sunny</LIGHT>
    <PRICE>500</PRICE>
    <AVAILABILITY>799</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
    <PLANT>
    <COMMON>carrot</COMMON>
    <BOTANICAL>Caltha</BOTANICAL>
    <ZONE>4</ZONE>
    <LIGHT>sunny</LIGHT>
    <PRICE>205</PRICE>
    <AVAILABILITY>679</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
    <FOOD>
    <NAME>daal fry</NAME>
    <PRICE>300</PRICE>
    <DESCRIPTION>
    Famous daal tadka from surat
    </DESCRIPTION>
    <CALORIES>60</CALORIES>
    </FOOD>
    <FOOD>
    <NAME>Dhosa</NAME>
    <PRICE>350</PRICE>
    <DESCRIPTION>
    The famous south indian dish
    </DESCRIPTION>
    <CALORIES>80</CALORIES>
    </FOOD>
    <FOOD>
    <NAME>Khichdi</NAME>
    <PRICE>150</PRICE>
    <DESCRIPTION>
    The famous gujrati dish
    </DESCRIPTION>
    <CALORIES>40</CALORIES>
    </FOOD>
    <BOOK>
      <AUTHOR>Santosh Bihari</AUTHOR>
      <TITLE>PHP Core</TITLE>
      <GENER>programming</GENER>
      <PRICE>44.95</PRICE>
      <DATE>2000-10-01</DATE>
   </BOOK>
   <BOOK>
      <AUTHOR>Shyam N Chawla</AUTHOR>
      <TITLE>.NET Begin</TITLE>
      <GENER>Computer</GENER>
      <PRICE>250</PRICE>
      <DATE>2002-17-05</DATE>
   </BOOK>
   <BOOK>
      <AUTHOR>Anci C</AUTHOR>
      <TITLE>Dr. Ruby</TITLE>
      <GENER>Computer</GENER>
      <PRICE>350</PRICE>
      <DATE>2001-04-11</DATE>
   </BOOK>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: For some reason creating a new variable with the exact same code after the `:` it started working again. For some reason it is only failing when I call the variable by the original name i gave it `findTag1`. Now that I'm calling in `findTag3` it works again. Why would this be?

Comment: Oh shoot, I just realized I have a typo causing this whole thing. `findaAll` instead of `findAll`. That's the issue. Ugh.

Comment: In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)